# Confusion about SQL error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a little bit confused with my sql-statement in PHP, because i do not use the `GROUP BY` function. I'm trying to determine just the players who participated in at least 10 games. So I add the following in my request `COUNT(DISTINCT(gameid)) > 9` and then received this SQL error.

```
SELECT 
  SUM(kills) as sum_kills, 
  SUM(deaths) as sum_death, 
  SUM(teamkills) as sum_teamkills, 
  SUM(suizide) as sum_suizide, 
  SUM(points) as sum_points, 
  aliases.hash as name, 
  aliases.rang as rang, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT(gameid)) as sum_games, 
  playerid 
FROM 
  stats_rounds_players, 
  aliases 
WHERE 
  aliases.id = playerid 
  AND COUNT(DISTINCT(gameid)) > 9 
  AND aliases.hash != ''
GROUP BY 
  playerid 
ORDER BY 
  sum_points DESC
```

i got following error message:

> #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Please tell me if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `HAVING` for your `WHERE COUNT(DISTINCT(gameid)) > 9` because you can't use `WHERE` with aggregates

[See here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)

> The HAVING clause was added to SQL because the WHERE keyword could not
>   be used with aggregate functions.

Something like (not tested):

```
SELECT 
  SUM(kills) as sum_kills, 
  SUM(deaths) as sum_death, 
  SUM(teamkills) as sum_teamkills, 
  SUM(suizide) as sum_suizide, 
  SUM(points) as sum_points, 
  aliases.hash as name, 
  aliases.rang as rang, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT(gameid)) as sum_games, 
  playerid 
FROM 
  stats_rounds_players, 
  aliases 
WHERE 
  aliases.id = playerid 
  AND aliases.hash != ''
GROUP BY 
  playerid 
HAVING 
  COUNT(DISTINCT(gameid)) > 9 
ORDER BY 
  sum_points DESC
```

Comment: Sidenote: this would be more maintainable/clear with `HAVING sum_games > 9`